# understanding javascript inheritance and node.js util inherits function example

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, inheritance

I have two modules: **apirequest.js** and **feed.js.** When I call `feed.start()` in **apirequest**, I get, `TypeError: Object #<Feed> has no method 'start'`. Why is this? Doesn't `util.inherits(Feed, APIRequest);` inherit APIRequest's properties?

**apirequest.js**

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var util = require('util');

function APIRequest(endpoint) { } 

APIRequest.prototype.start = function() { }

util.inherits(APIRequest, EventEmitter);

module.exports = APIRequest;
```

**feed.js**

```
var util = require('util');
var APIRequest = require('../lib/api_request');

function Feed(endpoint) {
  APIRequest.call(this, endpoint);
}

util.inherits(Feed, APIRequest);

var feed = new Feed(endpoint);

feed.start();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is order:

```
APIRequest.prototype.start = function() { }
util.inherits(APIRequest, EventEmitter); <-- *overwrites* APIRequest.prototype
```

If you swap those lines, it'll work:

```
util.inherits(APIRequest, EventEmitter);
APIRequest.prototype.start = function() { }
```

Comment: Thanks! Yep, I just did that and your answer came in;)